Web server flow is not working with custom login page for community user
I am using custom login form using site.login for community page in salesforce but when i am trying to use webservice flow and logging in woth user details its redirecting to community home page instead of redirect uri i have added.
Sample url - https://communitylink/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=clientId&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8080
Does anyone have idea about this ?
But if user is logged in and then i hit above url it is working fine.

The redirect URI must match one of the values in the connected app’s Callback URL field. Otherwise, the approval fails
